# Chainlink import causing Truffle console to crash

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin, chainlink, safemath

Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3329

If I compile my contracts with `truffle compile` and then open the truffle console with `truffle develop` then this happens:

```
truffle(develop)> version
Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
Solidity - ^0.6.0 (solc-js)
Node v12.18.2
Web3.js v1.2.1
truffle(develop)> TypeError: Buffer.isBuffer is not a function
    at Function.writeFileSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/write-file-atomic/index.js:213:1)
    at Configstore.set all [as all] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/configstore/index.js:58:1)
    at new Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/configstore/index.js:25:1)
    at Function.getUserConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/config/dist/index.js:171:1)
    at Object.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/services/analytics/index.js:5:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:137:1)
    at Console.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:155:1)
    at ReplManager.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/repl.js:129:1)
    at bound (domain.js:426:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:439:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:760:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:329:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:658:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:999:14)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (repl.js:851:9)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:205:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at emitKeys (internal/readline/utils.js:335:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>)
```

The reason seemed to be a naming conflict **(but it's not. well... it is but... see below)**. But as a side-question: Openzeppelin and chainlink both include a SafeMath contract:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> ...
> Compiling @chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMath.sol
> ...
> Compiling @openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol

> Duplicate contract names found for SafeMath.
> This can cause errors and unknown behavior. Please rename one of your contracts.
```

How can I use both chainlink and openzeppelin withouth running into this issue. Is this only possible with two completely separate contracts that only communicate through transactions? Or what do I not get here?

### UPDATE

So... the actual problem seems to be just chainlink and/or truffle.

While the question remains, how to resolve those naming conflicts, I realized that the `Buffer.isBuffer` issue has nothing to do with it but with chainlink/truffle itself it seems.

If I import for example something from openzeppelin, like Ownable, everything works fine. But if I import chainlink and inherit from ChainlinkClient, the truffle console crashes with above exception once I first compiled the contract.

I recorded this, see here: https://youtu.be/InNPguD3h6g

It turns out the native node object, Buffer, is being overwritten when you have a contract with this name. In general contract names can conflict with native node objects.

Related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3329

My project: https://github.com/mktcode/mergepay-contracts

Comment: I tried the same versions on Ubuntu 20.04 with metacoin example and it works as expected. I'd guess something is wrong in your setup try using nvm to install a separate instance of node, check is some of the project dependencies has a conflict with truffle. Also you should report your issue with truffle developers at github.com/trufflesuite/truffle.

Comment: @Ismael I'll do that now. I asked in their Gitter chat first but didn't get an answer yet.

Comment: Have you tried importing it into remix? Doing this might provide more information.

Comment: @T.Thomas The issue is resolved. Well, at least it's known what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently when using the Truffle console, it loads in all your contract names as a convenience so that you can access your deployed contracts etc. This, however, causes an issue when there are contract names that conflict with Node native objects; in this case the native `Buffer` object. It would be kind of like if you had a contract named "String". This would overwrite the native `String` object and it would become inaccessible.

So hopefully this is something that Truffle can fix, perhaps by providing a namespace for contract names that clash with names that already exist in that context.